# How to replace plus minus toggle with checkbox(tick untick) in HTML CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I want to replace plus minus expand toggle with the checkbox(plus,minus).Can I put plus minus in the checkbox for toggle. If I click on checkbox then minus sign change to plus and it will expand or vice versa. Plus minus should be in the checkbox. thanks in advance. My code is given below:-

[image]
[image]

HTML/CSS code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the unicode to a box and and a checked box in the CSS content (2610 and 2611).  See here:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.collapsible:after {
  content: '\2610';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2611";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I put plus minus in the checkbox for toggle,If I click on checkbox then minus sign change to plus and it will expand or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, you can do that simply adding some styling to the "check-box" section and keep your old unicode to keep the plus and minus. See what I did here: https://jsfiddle.net/7nh6xyds/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply replace the `<div>` header with a `<label>` and a `<checkbox>` and use the checkbox tag change event, also note that I change `this.nextElementSibling;` to `this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;` here is a working snippet for multiple elements:

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight){
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: #777;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: calc(100% - 36px);
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.collapsible input[type="checkbox"] {
  float:right;
}

.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<!--<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>-->
<label class="collapsible" for="toggle-collapsible">Open Section 1<input type="checkbox" name="toggle-collapsible" id="toggle-collapsible" class="toggle" /> </label>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

<!--<button class="collapsible">Open Section 1</button>-->
<label class="collapsible" for="toggle-collapsible2">Open Section 1<input type="checkbox" name="toggle-collapsible2" id="toggle-collapsible2" class="toggle" /> </label>

<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can I put plus minus in the checkbox for toggle,If I click on checkbox then minus sign change to plus and it will expand or vice versa

Comment: hmm, let me check! I got what you mean.

Comment: thanks Root,I got the solution.Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Sharadkumar, no problem! glad to help :)